# Creating an OpenID provider with DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to implement an OpenID provider with DotNetOpenAuth. I supply an OpenID url, and the consumer discovers my endpoint.

I log into my provider, and the provider returns a Claimed Identifier and a Local Identifier to the consumer.

But the consumer response has the following exception:

```
The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match. 
Assertion endpoint info: 
  ClaimedIdentifier: http://localhost/OpenIDUser.aspx/myuser
  ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://localhost/OpenIDUser.aspx/myuser 
  ProviderEndpoint: http://localhost/OpenIDAuth.aspx
  OpenID version: 2.0 
  Service Type URIs: 
Discovered endpoint info: []
```

`http://localhost/OpenIDAuth.aspx` is my endpoint.
`http://localhost/OpenIDUser.aspx/myuser` is my user identifier url, and I can browse to it successfully. It has a link to the endpoint in the header as follows:
`<link rel="openid.server" href="http://localhost/OpenIDAuth.aspx"></link>`

No matter what I try, the "Discovered endpoint info: []" part of the exception is always an empty array.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: It turns out the user identity url was protected in the forms authentication config, which stopped the discovery of the user identity from occurring successfully.

Answer (score 2):

It's puzzling that you got this far, because to see this error either the RP must have been able to successfully complete the discovery phase prior to redirecting to the Provider (in which case why would it fail the second time) or this is an unsolicited assertion (which is fine, but unusual).

But one flaw I see is that your tag:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://localhost/OpenIDAuth.aspx"></link>
```

is an advertisement for OpenID 1.1, whereas your Provider is asserting OpenID 2.0.  IIRC, the correct tag would be:

```
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://localhost/OpenIDAuth.aspx"></link>
```

And a tip: when you're developing a Provider and testing it with a DotNetOpenAuth RP, be sure to set the RP (and may be the OP too) to not cache discovery results in web.config, so that you know that successes and failures are actually current with your present code:

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>
    <openid cacheDiscovery="false">
```

You can see more configuration options, and the context in which the above xml appears [in the docs](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/configuration-options/).

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. My user identifier page does have `<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://localhost/OpenIDAuth.aspx"></link>` as well as the OpenID 1.1 link.

Comment: I removed a single line of whitespace from the user xrds document (under the first xml declaration) and I was able to sign in successfully! I added the line back to verify, and it stopped working. And removing the line again no longer works. I'm trying to debug the DotNetOpenAuth relying party code, but I get this error: `Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified`. I found a suggestion that I first run "sn -Vr *,2780CCD10D57B246 which I do, but I then get the error "Failed to open registry key".

Comment: You shouldn't be getting signing errors unless you're building DNOA yourself (which is typically not necessary).  As for the success, failure, then still failure scenario, you probably are experiencing discovery caching.  I've added to my answer to indicate how to turn that off during testing.

Comment: This didn't work for me. We have cacheDiscovery set to false and have tried eliminating any whitespace from the xrds.  Also, could you update the link to the docs?  Its a 404.  Any other suggestions on fixing this @AndrewArnott?